# Dimensionality vs dimension? (in physics context)

Tags: meaning-in-context

A question perhaps different from previously asked

Should I say:

In Gaussian units "sigma" has the same ***dimensionality*** as frequency...

(meaning that "sigma" is measured in the same units as frequency)

or

In Gaussian units "sigma" has the same ***dimension*** as frequency...

(sorry, this poster is not a native speaker...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belong to https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just say that they are measured in the same units. Why get abstract when you're delivering definite information.

Comment: @John, you are right, but I wanted to have a model for my other texts, so it would be nice to have it...

Answer (score 0):

**Dimensions.**  In *dimensional analysis*, you're typically interested in cancelling out the components of compound units in order to get a simpler result.  Most of the time you have multiple units, i.e.  a single *dimension* is the exception rather than the rule. It's true for frequency, though, where the SI dimensions are *1/s* (or for spatial frequency *1/m*).

*Dimensionality* seems excessive to me, since dimensional analysis is typically just a check on the consistency of your overall solution technique.  Kind of like referring to a *lifejacket* as a *personal flotation device*. But your readers will understand what you mean.

**Edited to add:**

In Gaussian units, where *sigma* is taken to mean electrical [conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity), dimensional analysis takes on a new twist.  The unit of conductivity is the reciprocal of the unit of resistivity.  The common unit of resistivity is the [ohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm), but this is actually a *derived unit*, i.e. its definition depends on physical properties that are measured in distance, time, mass and electrical charge.  The derivation in Gaussian units is different from the derivation in *Systeme International* (SI) units.  This results in *sigma* having the units of *1/s*, i.e. the dimensions of *1/T* (where *T* is time).

The fact that *conductivity* has the same units as *frequency* is mostly a curiosity, unless you're dealing with a physical phenomenon where the frequency of something is dependent on the conductivity of something else.

Comment: Thanks. OK, I'll try to be more specific. In "SI units", "sigma" and frequency have different units of measurement  ("sigma" is measured in  1/("resistance" * m), and frequency -- in 1/s.  Whereas in Gaussian units, they are measured in the SAME units -- 1/s. How I would expressed the latter statement in terms of "dimensions" ?

Comment: I'm using this Wikipedia article as my reference for Gaussian units: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units

Comment: By *sigma* and *frequency*, I assumed originally that you were referring to a standard deviation, and that frequency was a "physical frequency", as you might find in a distribution of frequencies.  I think I need more context to give you a solid answer.

Comment: @AlKap BTW, thanks for asking this question.  I had forgotten about Gaussian units and the history of the Ohm.

Answer (score 0):

Either would convey something of your intent, with *dimension* referring to the unit and *dimensionality* (something 'about' dimensions) referring to the *system* of units.

However, since there is often (at least) a constant factor between the corresponding Gaussian and SI units, neither *same dimension* nor *same dimensionality* conveys your intent fully, which is to say that they share the same units.

I'm not familiar with the Gaussian system in this context, but "**dimensionally equivalent**", as used in the Wikipedia entry, skirts the issue by using the word *equivalent* instead of the word *same*:

> A number of the units defined by the table have different names but are in fact dimensionally equivalent
>   [- Gaussian units, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units)

However, this reorders the phrase:

- X has the same dimension/dimensionality as Y.
- X and Y are dimensionally equivalent.

I echo [John Lawler's recommendation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/430231/dimensionality-vs-dimension-in-physics-context#comment1032389_430231) to drop *dimension/dimensionality* in favour of the plain *units*:

- X has the same units as Y.

Comment: Lawrence, thanks; you are editing my paper:-), but that is OK, I'll take that,  "X has the same units as Y",  albeit it pushes under the rug my intention to get attention to a peculiar fact. @Global Charm has got the flavor of my question: not many people know that the conductivity in Gaussian system has the same "dimension" as frequency (or the resistivity  -- the same as time...). There are very interesting ramifications of that, but this goes beyond this  forum... (BTW, the article on "Gaussian units" in Wikipedia is written by a guy who is a frequent user  in physics forum here...)